# Error: Return value of Grav\Plugin\ProblemsPlugin::autoload() must be an instance of Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader, int returned

Tags: php, grav

After testing my site locally with Xampp on windows everyhing works ok. The site is build with Grav. PHP version 8.2.0 on Xampp, 8.2.6 online
However after puting it online it gives the follopwing error:

Return value of Grav\Plugin\ProblemsPlugin::autoload() must be an instance of Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader, int returned

I already saw a question posted related to autoload() so hope to find an answer here.

I do have other Grav sites running, but never got this error. If this is not the right place to ask this question, just let me know. Ithought it might by php related and not directly related to Grav

Thanks!

I did change the php version to other versions but that did not solve it.
I installed it by copying all the files to a complete empty server.
Looked at a related question about autoload() on Stack Overflow

Error log says it comes from the line  $instance->setAutoloader($instance->autoload());
In the file Plugins.php

```
   public function init()
    {
        if ($this->plugins_initialized)  {
            return $this->items;
        }

        $grav = Grav::instance();

        /** @var Config $config */
        $config = $grav['config'];

        /** @var EventDispatcher $events */
        $events = $grav['events'];

        foreach ($this->items as $instance) {
            // Register only enabled plugins.
            if ($config["plugins.{$instance->name}.enabled"] && $instance instanceof Plugin) {
                // Set plugin configuration.
                $instance->setConfig($config);
                // Register autoloader.
                if (method_exists($instance, 'autoload')) {
                    $instance->setAutoloader($instance->autoload());
                }
                // Register event listeners.
                $events->addSubscriber($instance);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As you haven't shared the code, it's impossible to provide help

Comment: Added some code. Hope it is the right part

Comment: And what does `$instance->autoload()` return? Check that further, I would assume that (as given in the error message) any of the plugins returns a number

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: You could start by dumping `get_class($instance)` to see which plugin causes the problem

Comment: I will try to figure that out thanks. I have no experience with PHP.  Can I just enter this command just before the line where it crashes? like echo get_class($instance)?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Afterward, check what that specific plugin does when calling `autoload()`

Comment: I uploaded the stie once again after erasing everything. And now it works. Thanks for helping me out. But I screwed it up myself probably!